# In backbone.js view, how do i call another function from jquery $.each?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

In my backbone.js view i have a function that has the code below.  I would usually call this function using `this.addLayerToList()`, but since it's in the `$.each` this. is not what I want.  Can anyone help here?  How would I call my function addLayerToList from the `$.each`?

```
initLayerList: function(){
   $.each(baseLayers, function() {
       this.addLayerToList(this);
   });
},

addLayerToList : function() {
     //...some code here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
initLayerList: function(){
   var that = this;
   $.each(baseLayers, function(idx, layer) {
       that.addLayerToList(layer);
   });
},

addLayerToList : function() {
     //...some code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Backbone, [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) is also included and available to you. You can use Underscore's [each](http://underscorejs.org/#each) method, which lets you pass `this` into the context of your loop:

```
 initLayerList: function(){
      _.each(baseLayers, function(layer){
        this.addLayerToList(layer);
      }, this);

    },
    addLayerToList : function() {
         //...some code here
    }
```

If baselyayers is a Backbone [collection](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection), you can simplify the code a little further:

```
 initLayerList: function(){
      baseLayers.each(function(layer){
        this.addLayerToList(layer);
      }, this);

    }
```