# In backbone.js view, how do i call a function in the same view from a jquery event?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views

In my below example I am trying to call myfunction from the jquery event.  this is not right.  My event fires but I am not sure how to call this function from the event.  Ideas?

```
registerSliderControlEvents: function(){
    $("#slider-fill").on('slidestop', function (event) {
            //...some code

            this.myfunction(size);
        }
},

myfunction: function(size){
      //....some code
}
```

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138163/in-backbone-js-view-how-do-i-call-another-function-from-jquery-each) would have worked here as well :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're within a closure, the scope of `this` has changed. It's common practice to store `this` in a variable beforehand. Something similar to:

```
registerSliderControlEvents: function(){
    var self = this;
    $("#slider-fill").on('slidestop', function (event) {
            //...some code

            self.myfunction(size);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Backbone.View` events hash to avoid any issues with scope (see documentation [here](http://backbonejs.org/#View)). Something like the following:

```
events: {
    'slidestop #slider-fill': 'handleSlideStop' 
},

handleSlideStop: function() {
      // Not sure where size param is coming from, but assuming
      // you can set it as a property of the view somewhere.
      console.log('Size', this.size);
}
```

Another alternative would be to use underscore's bind method which will allow you to delegate the callback to a named function in your view and specify the scope in which it is called. This would look something like this:

```
registerSliderControlEvents: function(){
    $("#slider-fill").on('slidestop', _.bind(this.myFunction, this));
},

myfunction: function(size){
      //....some code
}
```

I always feel slightly dirty when I have to resort to `that` or `self` to resolve scope issues and will try to avoid it if possible. I'm pretty new to JavaScript, however, and perhaps just need to accept it as a necessary evil ;)